# Can't select part of hyperlink range

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

A hyperlink in my plugin contains 3 colors based on some conditions, before using hyperlink i used `documents.Range(start, end);` to change color and font.

But once added to the hyperlink the color is gone, actually I can't select part of hyperlink range, `documents.Range(start, end);` returns all range not part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formatting parts of a hyperlink is feasible. However, it is not straightforward. Hyperlinks are realized as Word fields, i.e. they consist of a field code and a display value (in fact, they are a *special* kind of field, not all of the relevant information such as the display text is stored in the field code).

You can reveal the field code by pressing Alt+F9 (and hide it again by pressing the same shortcut again).

When you set the start and end of the range to apply formatting, you need to consider that the field code is prepended to the display text (although by default you won't see the field code when looking at `Range.Text`). For example, if your hyperlink starts at offset 100, then the display text will actually start at offset 100 + *length of field code*.

This sample VBA macro explains how to retrieve the length of the field code and calculates the correct offset:

```
Sub FormatHyperlink()
    ' set up a sample document
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = Application.Documents.Add

    Selection.TypeText "This is a hyperlink to the "
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Selection.Range, _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/", , , "greatest webpage"
    Selection.TypeText " ever."

    ' retrieve the hyperlink
    Dim lnk As Hyperlink
    Set lnk = ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(1)

    ' retrieve the field code of the hyperlink
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = lnk.Range.Duplicate
    rng.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = True

    Dim fieldCodeLength As Integer
    fieldCodeLength = Len(rng.Text)

    rng.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = False

    ' format the first word of the display text with a different color
    rng.Start = rng.Start + fieldCodeLength + 1
    rng.Collapse
    rng.MoveEnd wdWord, 1
    rng.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed

    ' format the rest of the hyperlink with another color
    Set rng = lnk.Range.Duplicate
    rng.Start = rng.Start + fieldCodeLength + 1
    rng.MoveStart wdWord, 1
    rng.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue ' or use rng.Font.TextColor = RGB(x,x,x)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Hyperlink is changed from text into an Object Model object, the 'Hyperlink' object. This object has the Hyperlink style and this is what you see after changing it to the Hyperlink object.

You could change the Hyperlink style if you like to show the hyperlink in a different representation.

Comment: is there anyway to make hyperlink style like this picture http://prntscr.com/cns076  i want to split text to multi color